# .htaccess edits

Tags: themes, htaccess

WordPress newbie here, apologies if things don't make sense.

I bought a premium theme and uploaded/installed it to WordPress. Surely enough, after doing so, I found out that I was supposed to add the following values to .htaccess:

```
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value max_file_uploads 128M
php_value max_input_vars 5000
```

The authors are very adamant to do this BEFORE installing and activating the theme, but that's already too late in my case.

What's the appropriate course of action here, deactivate and delete the theme in question in order to add those lines to .htaccess?

Comment: If your default server values are already greater than those settings then there should be no problem adding them after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Just switch the theme, then delete the theme you bought and after edited the `.htaccess` reinstall it.
This should work without problems. If you have access to cpanel, set the values from the php settings section instead of rely on the `.htaccess` file.